# Exit For in vb.net will not exit

Tags: vb.net

I have these for loops:

```
For x = search_phone.Length To 0 Step -1
                    For m = 1 To number_call_costs
                        If search_phone.Substring(0, x) = call_costs_data(m, 2) Then
                            match = True

                            customer_cost = callcost_lookup("sequence", call_costs_data(m, 1), customer_sequence, "cost")
                            customer_connection = callcost_lookup("sequence", call_costs_data(m, 1), customer_sequence, "connection")
                            description = call_costs_data(m, 3)
                            MsgBox(call_costs_data(m, 3))
                            Exit For
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
```

the data i am testing with is:

```
search_phone = '101'
call_costs_data(m, 2) = one row is '1' and another row is '101'
```

its matching `search_phone` to `101` in the loop but its not exiting, because its matching again to `1`

Comment: That second Exit For won't be reached.  At the end of the the x loop, try `If match = True Then Exit For`.

Comment: ah of course! Doh! so put the other `Exit For` after the first `Next` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That second exit won't be reach, so try it like this:

```
For x As Integer = search_phone.Length To 0 Step -1
  match = False
  For m As Integer = 1 To number_call_costs
    If search_phone.Substring(0, x) = call_costs_data(m, 2) Then
      match = True
      '// code...
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  If match Then
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: @charlie yes, preferrably.